# Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo Ideapad - Can't get it to recognize USB Keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboard, 18.04, lenovo

I have a Das Keyboard that was just gifted to me recently, and I'd like to use it on my Lenovo laptop. When I first plugged it in, it worked. Then I had to restart a couple days ago, and I haven't been able to get it to work ever since. It won't even show up when I do lsusb, so when I do dmesg, it shows me this (truncated):

```
[  123.174691] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[  123.302592] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  123.538221] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  123.773988] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[  123.902039] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  124.138200] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  124.246144] usb usb1-port3: attempt power cycle
[  124.897060] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[  124.897265] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[  125.105047] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[  125.312629] usb 1-3: device not accepting address 16, error -71
[  125.440659] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[  125.440872] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[  125.649011] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[  125.856604] usb 1-3: device not accepting address 17, error -71
[  125.856738] usb usb1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```

I've done the obvious, which is shutting down, unplugging everything and letting it sit (even over night.) I changed the autosuspend (used "autosuspend" instead of "autosuspend_delay_ms" because the former took when I rebuilt the boot file.) I can't remember what else. Nothing has worked so far, unless I'm just doing it incorrectly.

I'm asking two questions: a.) is there something different I could do that would work in Ubuntu 18, and b.) what specifically does "error -71" mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I have found some info referring to an error with newer Gigabyte Motherboards.
Have a look in: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72625/why-is-usb-not-working-in-linux-when-it-works-in-uefi-bios

EDIT:
Basically you may need to enable the option `IOMMU Controller` in your BIOS, also `XHCI` and `EHCI` if it's available.